# Uncaught ReferenceError: handleClick is not defined react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Can anyone please explain to me why when I run this code I got this error : App.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: handleClick is not defined.[the code in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt6JE.png)

but when I changed it to the code below it worked[the code that works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xsdad.png)

Comment: Please add code ref not image and the reason is that you are defining the function out of App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the first case, you are using a function component and this inside function component is undefined, so when you call the function using
this.handleClick() it gives you a reference error.

But at the same time in the class component, it works because this refers to the object, which is an instance of the class Component

You need to move handleClick to the component function.

```
export default function App() {
  const handleClick = () => { ... }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move `handleClick` to the component function.

```js
export default function App() {
  const handleClick = () => { ... }
  ...
}
```

And call it without the `this` keyword:

```html
<Button onPress={() => {
  handleClick(item.link)
}}>Top to view course</Button>
```